# Using arrays in Oracle SDO_GEOMETRY

Tags: sql, oracle, varray

I am having some issues with Oracle SQL as I am learning how to use it, but one thing seems not to be working and I cant see why:

I am trying to use the SDO_GEOMETRY objects to update a coordinate value in a table. I am trying to declare VARRAYs, filling these arrays with the coordinates and ELEM_INFO needed, and passing these arrays into the SDO_GEOMETRY obejct in the `update` part, like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE decimal_array is varray(728) OF NUMBER (10,9); 
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE int_array IS VARRAY(67) OF INTEGER; 
> /

DECLARE 

sdo_ordinate_arr decimal_array := decimal_array(2,4, 4,3, 10,3, 13,5, 13,9, 11,13, 5,13, 2,11, 2,4, 7,5, 7,10, 10,10, 10,5, 7,5); 
info_arr int_array := int_array(1,1003,1, 19,2003,1);

begin 

update schema.table set geo_coord = (SDO_GEOMETRY(2003, 25832, NULL, 
SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(info_arr), SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(sdo_ordinate_arr))) where id = 123456;

END; 
> /
```

I tried the SQL above, and expected it to work, but it did not. There are no errors being raised, but the value in the table is not being updated.

If i do it like this, without the arrays but using the same values, it works:

```
update schema.table set geo_coord_ = (SDO_GEOMETRY(2003, 25832, NULL, 
SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1,1003,1, 19,2003,1), SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(2,4, 4,3, 10,3, 13,5, 13,9, 11,13, 5,13, 2,11, 2,4, 7,5, 7,10, 10,10, 10,5, 7,5))) where id = 123456;
```

As I understand from the documentation, `SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY` and `SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY` are both declared as arrays. Why doesnt it work if passed an array as value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it, you need to declare your arrays as SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY and SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY, not as VARRAYs:

```
sdo_ordinate_arr SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY:= SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(2,4, 4,3, 10,3, 13,5, 13,9, 11,13, 5,13, 2,11, 2,4, 7,5, 7,10, 10,10, 10,5, 7,5)

info_arr SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY := SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1,1003,1, 19,2003,1)
```

Oracle is confusing.